# Why did the 'Reality Dysfunction' book series end with a Deus ex Machina?

Tags: plot-device, nights-dawn-trilogy

Why did the 'Reality Dysfunction' book series end with a Deus ex Machina?  I mean he runs across a sentient super computer black hole with limitless power acting as a wish granting genie?  I understand it wouldn't have been easy resolve all the issues but really disappointing.  Does anyone know why?  (Manuscript due date, lazy, etc.)

Comment: It sounds like he struggled with it; http://www.lysator.liu.se/lsff/mb-nr33/Peter_F_Hamilton.html

Comment: The author discusses it at some length here; https://sfbook.com/interview-with-peter-f-hamilton.htm

Comment: Considering that he'd been looking for that supercomputer thingamajig for hundreds and hundreds of pages at that point, I don't think it truly qualifies as a "Deus ex Machina." Not in the classic sense of "suddenly ***and unexpectedly***, a godlike entity appears onstage and works a miracle to wrap up the plot." Instead, it was "after a long, hard quest, the hero finds the godlike entity which he has good reason to believe might be able to work a miracle to wrap up the plot -- and indeed it does!"